# PDO bind variables to prepared mysql statement and fetch using while loop

Tags: pdo, while-loop, bindparam

I've used several of your guides but I can not get the following to run.  If I hardcode the 2 variables in the Select statement it runs fine.  I need to use variables, and I can't get the bind statement to work.  Plenty of experience with the old Mysql_ but the PDO is still a challenge at this point.

```
$db_table = "ad";
$ID       = "1";

$dsn = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

$pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM :ad WHERE id= :id ");    //  Line 359 
$result->bindParam(':ad', $db_table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':id', $ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $product    = $row["product"];
    $msrp       = $row["msrp"];
    $sale       = $row["sale"];
    $content    = $row["content"];
    echo "<strong>$product</strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;$content<br />";
    // echo $msrp . "<br />";
    if($msrp != "0.00") { echo "MSRP $$msrp";  }
    if($sale != "0.00") { echo "<img src='/images/c.gif' width='75' height='6' border='0'><span style='color: red;'>Sale $$sale</span>"; }
    }

$pdo = null;
```

The above generates this error,

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right  syntax to use
>   near '? WHERE id=?' at line 1' in
>   /XXXXXXXXXXXX/index_desktop_pdo.php:359

Comment: Trying putting a space between id and = ``WHERE id = :id``

Comment: No luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure is wrong. There should be **always only one table** to hold all the similar data. And therefore no need to make a variable table name.

To distinguish different parts of data just add another *field* to this table. This is how databases work.

So your code should be

```
$section = "ad";
$ID      = "1";

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE section=:ad AND id= :id");
$result->bindParam(':ad', $section);
$result->bindParam(':id', $ID);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: Wasn't the space between id and the equal sign.

Comment: Don't you understand what is written in my answer?

Comment: I believe the database structure is fine the one table is "ad" and it's a variable. The field is id and it's also a variable.  Unless the table itself can't be a bindParam.

Comment: Well that's oxymoron. If you have a table id as a variable, then your design is not ok. But you can keep with your ideas. The more your kind, the more money will earn someone who will end up fixing that mess.

Comment: You've never needed to pass in the name of a table.  How inflexible is that?

Comment: For your example it is absolutely unnecessary. If you manage to provide a real life example where you need a variable table name, then there will be a different answer.